# Android ListView only last row on button click

Tags: java, android, listview

I have the following code:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView camera;
    TextView players;
    TextView max_players;
    ImageView privata;
    Button Buton;
}
ViewHolder holder;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String variabile[] = getItem(position).split("\\s+");

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater linflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.camera = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Nume);
        holder.players = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.players);
        holder.max_players = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.max_players);
        holder.privata = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.privata);
        holder.Buton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Buton);
        holder.camera.setText(variabile[0]);
        if (!variabile[1].equals("true")) {
            parola = false;
            holder.privata.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        holder.players.setText(variabile[2]);
        holder.max_players.setText(variabile[3]);
        room_id = variabile[4];
        nume = variabile[5];
        holder.Buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hash.put("name", nume);
                hash.put("room", room_id);
                if (intra) {
                    holder.Buton.setText("Iesi");
                    site = siteul + "/join";
                    intra = false;
                } else {
                    holder.Buton.setText("Intra");
                    site = siteul + "/leave";
                    intra = true;
                }
                new ATask().execute(site);
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    return convertView;
}
```

I'm trying to access a row from an AsyncTask on PostExecute and modify it like this:

```
TextView players_mare = holder.players;
players_mare.setText(rez.substring(2));
```

No matter the button pressed it seems to modify the textview of the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `holder`. After rendering complete `ListView` it has reference of the last item in the `ListView`, so only last item is updated irrespective of the item on which button was clicked. You need to pass the reference of item in which button was clicked to the `ATask` class.

1. Add

   ```
   holder.Buton.setTag(holder);
   ```

   after

   ```
   convertView.setTag(holder);
   ```

   in `getView()` method
2. Create a class level variable in `ATask` clas like this

   ```
   ViewHolder myHolder;
   ```
3. Add this in `ATask`

   ```
   public ATask(ViewHolder view) {
       myHolder = view;
   }
   ```
4. Change `ATask` call like this

   ```
   new ATask((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).execute(site);
   ```
5. In `PostExecute` replace every `holder` with `myHolder`

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to behave the same way. I call the Atask by `new ATask().execute((ViewHolder)v.getTag());` in the OnClick listener as the ATask looks like this `public class ATask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, String>` .

Comment: But that's not what I suggested. Please check again from point 1 to 5

Comment: Perfect. Glad could help.